# Consume Dynamics NAV web service in Visual Studio using Digest authentication issues

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, digest-authentication, dynamics-nav

I recently posted about an issue with 401 errors when accessing a Dynamics NAV 2018 web service using NTLM. This can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201072/dynamics-nav-web-service-call-with-c-sharp-succeeds-after-401-errors)

Because Dynamics NAV has multiple options for authentication, we are attempting to use the "Username" option which uses Digest authentication instead to stop these 401 errors.

Details about the Dynamics NAV credential type options can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/users-credential-types)

The issue were having is this...

If we leave the existing web proxy classes in our C# solution as they are when they were added (when the web service was using the Windows credential type with NTLM) but change the authentication type when we call the web service AFTER it has been set to Digest on the web service server, we authenticate successfully and we get a 200 response when we use our application.

BUT, when we attempt to access the same web service directly using Chrome (so we can debug using Wizdler) we can't authenticate and a 400 error is generated.

However, if there are changes to the web service, and its set to use Username, and we attempt to update our web references, we're constantly prompted for the username and password in Visual Studio. Every time you enter the credentials needed, the same username and password prompt is presented again. I've entered it at least 20 times in a row and it just doesn't get passed this stage. This means that once the Dynamics NAV web service credential type is set to Username, we're no longer able to update our web references.

I cant help thinking I'm missing a part of this puzzle but I have no idea what shape or colour it is!

The web service server is using SSL and the services are accessible at their https address (when I run the application it authenticates successfully remember)

All we need to do to have our end goal, is to allow Visual Studio to update the web reference, and to be able to access the service from Chrome/Wizdler when the web service Credential type is Username (which uses Digest).

Does anyone have any experience of this setup, or know if this is doomed to fail and will never work?